# AJAX UpdatePanel Causes Entire Page Postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, autopostback

I am facing a problem that I cannot solve!

I have two DropDownLists inside an UpdatePanel with `AutoPostBack=true`, `UpdateMode="always"`, `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` and `EnableViewState="false"`.

The values shown inside the second DropDownList are dependent of the SelectedValue on the first one.

Whenever the selected value on a DropDownList, the entire page is postback. I want only the postback running inside the updatepanel.

Note: The ScriptManager has `EnablePartialRendering="true"`.

What should I do?

Comment: perhaps post the markup?

Comment: What do you mean by "the entire page is postback"? you cant get an async post back or you are referring to the quantity of data sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Well you must have wrapped the whole page inside the Update Panel i suppose and also as i suspect `UpdateMode="always"` is the cukprit. Change that to Conditional. Because the update panel is going to be refreshed only on children triggers and not when anyhting and everything happens on the page.